# $\log(z)$ for $|z| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

So what I want to have is image of $\log(z)$ for $e^{-\pi/4} < |z| < e^{\pi/4}$.

So from what I have been able to figure out for the image is that the new magnitude of circle will be $\log(|z|)$ while the argument of the number will stay same. However the log of 1 is zero, I'm not able to imagine where the circle with radius of magnitude $e^{-\pi/4}$ which is less than 1.

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: In polar coordinates, $\log z = \log (r \exp (i \phi)) = \log r +  i \phi $ and again (with $z = x + i y$) in cartesian coordinates $ = 0.5 \log (x^2 + y^2)  +  i \arctan (y/x) $. Just plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's quite easy to write $z$ down given $e^{-\pi/4}<|z|<e^{\pi/4}$; we can just write

$$z=re^{i\theta}$$

with $e^{-\pi/4}<r<e^{\pi/4}$ a real number and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Now what happens when we throw this into $\log$? Well,

$$\log(z)=\log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh thank you.. had  created a wrong image in my mind, Thank you.